# How to check if a MySQL query using the legacy API was successful?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check if a MySQL query is successful other than using `die()`

I'm trying to achieve...

```
mysql_query($query);

if(success){
//move file
}
else if(fail){
//display error
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is the first example in the manual page for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

If you wish to use something other than `die`, then I'd suggest [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: Or simply `if (!mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1')) { ... }`

Comment: @Rune: Right, but then you won't be able to use the query resource for further actions (i.e. for fetching actual data using `mysql_fetch_*` functions).

Comment: @AmalMurali hmm, good point. I'm not sure where I was with my head at the time of posting that comment..

Comment: Use `$result === false` not `!$result`.  REASON: There may be queries for which `$result` is a VALID (non-error) value that is equivalent to ZERO. (I think an empty string is another example.)  In php, `!0` evaluates to `true`, so your `die` would execute, even though is not an error.   SIMILARLY, when you want the opposite test, for code that should execute when there is not an error, use `if ($result !== false)` rather than `if ($result)`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`mysql_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) for this too.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_errno()){
    echo "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": "
         .mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing <br>\n$query\n<br>";
}
```

Comment: It's much more reliable using mysql_errno(), because you can't quite rely on the type of result returned from mysql_query().

Answer (score 4):

If your query failed, you'll receive a FALSE return value. Otherwise you'll receive a resource/TRUE.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result){
    /* check for error, die, etc */
}
```

Basically as long as it's not false, you're fine. Afterwards, you can continue your code.

```
if(!$result)
```

This part of the code actually runs your query.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` function is used for executing mysql query in php. `mysql_query` returns false if query execution fails.Alternatively you can try using `mysql_error()` function
For e.g

```
$result=mysql_query($sql)
```

or

```
die(mysql_error());
```

In above code snippet if query execution fails then it will terminate the execution and display mysql error while execution of sql query.

Answer (score 1):

put only :

`or die(mysqli_error());`

after your query

and it will retern the error as `echo`

example

```
// "Your Query" means you can put "Select/Update/Delete/Set" queries here
$qfetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("your query")) or die(mysqli_error()); 



    if (mysqli_errno()) {
        echo 'error' . mysqli_error();
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if using `MySQLi` bind_param try to put this line above the query

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```