# Is mysql return data to php variable when error

Tags: php, mysql

so i created php variable contain mysql query inside , but is it will return data to the php variable when the table / column / data is not available ?

**example :**

```
 $a1='1';
$item1nanowr = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM item_info WHERE item_special_number = $a1 ");
```

now just imagine that `item_name` column not available , is it will return data ?

and if i put "or die" statement like this :

```
$item1nanowr = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM item_info WHERE item_special_number = $a1 ") or die("Coming Soon");
```

is it will return word Coming Soon  ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918797/how-to-check-if-a-mysql-query-was-successful

Comment: How difficult can it be to try this out and discover for yourself?

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or die()` will run only if something goes wrong with the query. Several things could go wrong. Some of them are:

- The database table does not exist
- One of the specified columns does not exist
- There is a syntax error in the query
- The database is offline or the connection has been lost

So it will run on critical errors. It won't run if your table or a specific column is empty.

Also it is very important to stop using `mysql_` functions!. The `mysql` extension is deprecated from PHP 5.5 and completely removed from PHP 7.

Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. You should also use Prepared Statements instead of directly interpolating variables in your query. More on Prepared Statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: ok now i understand the "or die" , but how about if i didn't put "or die
"

Comment: You need to run the query, fetch the result and then check if it's empty or not. The way to do that depends on the interface that you decide to use be it `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` is useless, no need to keep using it or learning it.